# python oci: Oracle Cloud Infrastructure: How to list files in a bucket

Tags: python, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I am trying to print the files in a bucket on Oracle cloud. I have installed oci library for it and came this far. Now I dont know further how to get list of files in a particular bucket.

```
import os,oci
from oci.config import validate_config

tenancyId="sdkfh" # Your tenancies OCID.
authUserId="sdjfs"; # The OCID of the user ID being used.
OCI_KEY_PATH="filename"; # Path of the key file.
keyFingerprint="12:13:14:15"; # The fingerprint of the key file being used

config = {
    "user": authUserId,
    "key_file": OCI_KEY_PATH,
    "fingerprint": keyFingerprint,
    "tenancy": tenancyId,
    "region": "us-phoenix-1"
}

validate_config(config)

identity = oci.identity.IdentityClient(config)
user = identity.get_user(config["user"]).data
print(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the objects inside the bucket.

```
import os,oci
from oci.config import validate_config

tenancyId="sdkfh" # Your tenancies OCID.
authUserId="sdjfs"; # The OCID of the user ID being used.
OCI_KEY_PATH="filename"; # Path of the key file.
keyFingerprint="12:13:14:15"; # The fingerprint of the key file being used
namespace = "xyz"
bucket_name = "abc"
config = {
    "user": authUserId,
    "key_file": OCI_KEY_PATH,
    "fingerprint": keyFingerprint,
    "tenancy": tenancyId,
    "region": "us-phoenix-1"
}
#it validates the above fields for connection
validate_config(config)
# prefix and fields are optional paramater.
#prefix is for filename pattern but not a regex
#fields valid values - md5,name,timeCreated,size
object_storage_client = oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient(config)
object_list = object_storage_client.list_objects(namespace, bucket_name, prefix = filename , fields="name,timeCreated,size")
for o in object_list.data.objects:
    print(o.name)
```

Output:
List of files inside the bucket with given fields

Suppose you want those files which are starting like filename*, than give prefix as filename. As it is not a regex so * and other things will not work. Here, i am not able to get time last modified and various other fields. If someone knows about it please let me know here.
Python SDK for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Github Link to [source](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk).

Comment: Why prefix = 1? Won't that limit the returned results?

Comment: Prefix is for file pattern. Also, note that its not regex. I will update my answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I see the question has already been answered, but there is a more elegant way to manage the credentials here. I would demonstrate the same code using that.

OCI has a directory for user credentials of every user located at ~/.oci/config. This config file uses a syntax similar to INI files. A sample of the same looks like this:

```
[<profile-name>]
user=<user-ocid>
key_file=<private-key-path>
region=<region-name>
tenancy=<tenancy-ocid>
fingerprint=<public-key-fingerprint>
```

Now this profile can be used by the OCI CLI and the Python SDK. You can easily read the credentials using a simple function from the package.

```
from oci.config import from_file

config = from_file(profile_name=<profile-name>)
```

Now you can simply use this config object to perform any further operations.